# Changing the event handler by using a recursion

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I'm unsure of how this can be done, and have tried the following to no avail:

```
someElement.onmouseover=function(event) {
 if(!event) { e = window.event; }
 if(event.typeof=="mouseup") {
  //change what [i]this[/i] returns (this = null doesn't work either)
  //and how could I find a way to allow this event handler to alter itself under the       
 }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nothing in your question makes sense to me. Could you describe the end result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry.  I want to have an event handler change the way it functions by means of recursion, and specifically to have a way for it to trigger that change on the condition of an event for a foreign object transpiring (e.g. so, for aElement.onmouseover to occur, and if the handler for that event finds that bElement.onmouseup to transpire, then for aElement.onmouseover to return false).

Answer (score 0):

```
> someElement.onmouseover=function(event)
> {  if(!event) { e = window.event; }
```

I think you mean:

```
  event = window.event
```

.

```
> if(event.typeof=="mouseup") {
```

I think you mean:

```
  if (event.type == 'mouseup') {
```

.

```
> //change what [i]this[/i] returns
> (this = null doesn't work either)
```

The value of a function's *this* keyword is set during instantiation, you can't change it.

```
> //and how could I find a way to allow
> this event handler to alter itself
> under the         } }
```

Alter itself? It can set a different **listener**, if that's what you mean:

```
this.onmouseover = someOtherFunction;
```

### Edit

Play with this:

```
<script>
  function showType(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
  }
</script>

<input
  onclick="showType(event);"
  onmouseover="showType(event);"
  onmouseout="showType(event);"
  onmousedown="showType(event);"
  onmouseup="showType(event);"
  onkeydown="showType(event);"
  onkeyup="showType(event);"
  onkeypress="showType(event);"
  value="Do stuff in here"
>
```

Comment: Thanks.  if(event.type=="mouseup") doesn't respond if the mouse button is relased, nor does event.typeof.

Comment: Help, please? :( Is there anything I'm doing wrong that's preventing me from getting the event type? What I need to do is get the event type from within an event handler, and then check the source of that event and then change the current listener under some condition.

Comment: *event.type* is the event [type](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-type), the various properties of an event object are listed in the [W3C Events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/) under [interface Event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event).